# How can I convert a tif or xyz file to HGT?

Tags: convert, hgt

Due to system incompatibilities between projects, I have been asked to convert my DEM which is in geotif format to HGT.

I have no experience with HGT and cannot find any export options to this format.

Would anyone now if/how I can do this?

Yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with the -of flag set to 'SRTMHGT' but note the restrictions in the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html).